# How to calculate a set with a negative letter set?

Tags: python, math, set

Sets are given, and a new set must be found(in the foto). What to do with negation in this case?

```
A = set('mdrci')
B = set('pdnuy')
C = set('rinl')
D = set("plcyezt")
    
F = (not A).union(B) | (C.difference(D))
print(F)
```

Mistake: AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'union'
[image])

Comment: It's not possible to do `not A` with Python sets. How can you make a set of every possible value that isn't in `A`?

Comment: What do you expect from `not A`? In python it gives you a boolean telling you if `A` contains anything. If you have a universal set `U`, then you should specifically define `not_A = U - A` and use `not_A`

Comment: There's no such thing as a `set` that incorporates "all things that are not in this other `set`". If you have a specific end result that you expect or limitations on the set space (e.g. valid members restricted to lowercase ASCII alphabetic characters), it's possible "real world `set`s" can be made to produce that result in some way, but the result cannot encompass an unbounded notion of "all the things not in a given set".

Comment: `¬A∧B` is equivalent to `B∖A` (or in Python syntax, just `B - A`). No need for any universal sets.

Answer (score 0):

If you can define a limited notion of the universal set for your problem, this can be made to work by defining your "inverses" in terms of subtracting from the universal set. So for example, if your universal set is "lowercase ASCII alphabetic characters", you could do:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

U = frozenset(ascii_lowercase)  # Defines the universe of possible values up front

A = set('mdrci')
B = set('pdnuy')
C = set('rinl')
D = set("plcyezt")

F = (U - A).union(B) | C.difference(D)
```

as `U - A` produces a fully realized `frozenset` containing all the letters in the universe that aren't in `A`.

I'll note, the set operation described between A and B in the image is an *intersection* operation, not union, so the actual final code should be:

```
F = (U - A).intersection(B) | C.difference(D)
```

or for slightly less verbosity by using syntax operators consistently:

```
F = ((U - A) & B) | (C - D)
```

Comment: `(U - A) & B` could simply be replaced with `B - A` (assuming that `U` is a superset of both `A` and `B`).

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Good point. I'll leave it written as is (since I'm not 100% sure what the OP wants and optimizing too much risks making it harder to fix for the OP's real use case), but that would be a good optimization for this specific case.